Unable to save to Sent Items folder when sending from a shared mailbox using Graph Api
We are using the Graph API to read and send mail from a shared mailbox. However when we send an email it is not being saved to the "Sent Items" folder of that shared mailbox. The app authenticates using an Entra Application with the following permissions.
Entra permissions
We are calling the Graph API from a ASP.NET app using the Microsoft.Graph NuGet package Version 5.56.0.
The app authenticates like so:
private async Task<GraphServiceClient> InitGraphServiceClient()  
{
    var clientSecret = await GetClientSecret();
    var settings = graphSettings.Value;
    var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(settings.TenantId, settings.ClientId, clientSecret);
    return new GraphServiceClient(credential, ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]); 
}

And then uses the following code to send the email:
// ... code above omitted
var fromAddr = "<shared-mailbox-email-address>"; // Injected from configuration
var requestBody = new SendMailPostRequestBody
{
    Message = new Message
    {
        Subject = subject,
        Body = new ItemBody
        {
            ContentType = BodyTypeToGraphApiBodyType(bodyType),
            Content = body
        },
        ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
        {
            new()
            {
                EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                {
                    Address = to
                },
            },
        },
        Attachments = attachments.Select(
                a => new FileAttachment
                {
                    OdataType = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
                    ContentBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(a.Base64Content),
                    Name = a.Name,
                    ContentType = a.ContentType,
                } as Microsoft.Graph.Models.Attachment
            )
            .ToList()
    },
    SaveToSentItems = true
};

var graphServiceClient = await graphServiceClientProvider.GetGraphServiceClientAsync();
await graphServiceClient.Users[fromAddr].SendMail.PostAsync(requestBody);

Everything works great except the sent item is not saved in the Sent Items folder of the shared mailbox. The email is recieved by the recipient just fine, and the "From" address is set to the shared mailbox like expected.
So far I've tried the following:

Including the 'From' and/or 'Sender' properties in the request body
Removing the 'SaveToSentItems = true' based on this documentation found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body

Neither of these things seemed to have any effect so I'm left wondering how to resolve this.

I have got same problem.
It is saved in sentitems by following code:
var savedDraft = await graphClient
  .Users[fromAddr]
  .Messages
  .PostAsync(Message);

await graphClient
    .Users[fromAddr]
    .Messages[savedDraft.Id]
    .Send
    .PostAsync();

